# How to correctly compare 2 different queries from database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to PHP and I was trying to compare 2 different queries from database. They both have multiple array and I want to check a date.

This is the first query:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM users
LEFT JOIN normalDay
ON  normalDay.user_id=users.id";

$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

The second one:

```
$sql2=" SELECT holidays.date, normalDay.id FROM normalDay
LEFT JOIN holidays
ON normalDay.date=holidays.date";

$query2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
```

Both them have multiple arrays and I want to check if a date from 'normalDay' is in 'holidays' too. I tried accessing arrays with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, with something like this:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
       if($row['date']==$row2['date']){
            some code here
           }
      }
  }
```

This returns null. I tried to approach it in some different ways too, but still same thing.

The tables from both queries:
Table 1

| user_id | date | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022/01/01 | *** |
| 2 | 2022/01/01 | *** |
| 1 | 2022/01/02 | *** |
| 3 | null | *** |

Table 2

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022/01/01 |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | null |
| 4 | null |

So how can I check in this example if the `2022/01/01` date is in both queries?
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Why not do this in one query?

Comment: AD7six is right, you can use [`IN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) to check whether a given value is on the other list. also, you will have nulls whenever you used `left join` (or `right join`) but no match can be found on the other table. a concrete use-case would help in formulating the query you need.

Comment: I needed it with 2 queries guys. Tried again but still nothing. So the only way is making it with single query?

Comment: Why? What’s your actual goal here, the structure of the queries don’t help you to “compare two queries” so it’s unclear why you are trying to do it this way. Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: It was specified in my project that had to be done with 2 queries

Comment: That is a weird requirement, without some further explanation I suggest that’s a misunderstanding. In any event this is _mostly_ an sql question, and doesn’t/shouldn’t have any need for php logic as asked.

Answer (score 0):

check with the `in_array` function

You can do it this way like:

```
$result_array = array();
$found = false;
for($i=0; $i<count($query_1); $i++) {
$found = false;
for($j=0; $j<count($query_1[$i]['date']); $j++) {
if(in_array($query_1[$i]['date'][$j], $query_2) && !$found) {
  $result_array[] = $query_1[$i];
  $found = true;
}
}
}
print_r($result_array);
```

Comment: In the $query_2 array it must be a single array otherwise it's not working.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.  The query doesn't return single array

Comment: you can use this for multidimensional to convert single array 
`$array = array_column($query_2, 'date');`

Comment: You’ll find it a lot easier to do/read if you convert query2 to a flat array of values before iterating - you’ll only need one for each loop then